# How to get my current time

Tags: java, datetime

**Introduction**

I wanted to get my computer's current time in the format of HH:MM:SS. Although I tried a lot of different methods, they are all giving me the same result.

**Code**

```
long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

System.out.println(hours +":" + minutes+ ":"+ seconds);
```

**Result**

12:42:34 but my computer's current time is 8:42:34

**What I want**

But the time is different from my computer's current time. Why?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Head First Java is a GREAT starter book for those with some OO background but want to learn basics of Java. It has a great chapter on formatting for multiple inputs and included many calls for date and time as well as the use of Date vs Calendar.

Comment: Also, it seems to me your output is due to time zone. Most millisecond calls are based is Eastern Time Zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `currentTimeMillis` method returns time in UTC time.  Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instance to format the time in your current TimeZone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

use `hh:mm:ss` format for getting hour in am/pm (1-12) .
use `HH:mm:ss` format for getting hour in 24 hour format .
For more details [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Is there any credence to adding some String.format calls? Like %td for day or %tB for month? Also, the use of the < operand for multiple formats for a single input? I ask because it was discussed in a basics book I read.

Answer (score 1):

Try dis

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: I've read that date has mostly been superceded by calendar, has this been your experience? Or is it just a matter of which one fits the bill? I ask because a book I finished reading seems to highly favor Calendar.

Comment: @JeremyJohnson `Date` is simply a wrapper around a UNIX timestamp. `Calendar` stores `TimeZone` information and whatnot. Whichever fits the bill really.